# The Contact form not is sending email

Tags: forms, tags, submit, contacts, add-on

I have a problem with the contact form not sending email after submission. I have checked the tags and it is correct. It was working before. I badly need help. The Contact Add-on hasn't been changed. Can I ask a remedy for this?

Comment: Share your code with us to get help!

Comment: I am using the contact Add-on of PYROCMS. It uses tags on the page itself.

Comment: {{ contact:form name="text|required" email="text|required|valid_email" subject="dropdown|Guest Inquiry|Feedback" message="textarea" attachment="file|zip" to="hospicio323@yahoo.com" }}


Name:
{{ name }}

Email:
{{ email }}

Subject: {{ subject }}

Message:

{{ message }}

Attach a zip file: {{ attachment }}


{{ /contact:form }}

Comment: Please. I need help. I am just using PYROCMS. Its not sending email. Its the contact add-on that I am using so the code is the same.